# Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined get method

Tags: javascript

```
function s() 
{
    alert("hello");
    $email = document.getElementById("inp_subscribe").value;
    alert($email);
    $.get("subscribe.php",{inp_subscribe: $email },"");
    alert($email);
}
```

Please help me to learn how to get this `$.get()` function to work.

Comment: Are you assuming _jQuery_? Have you included a reference to the framework you're assuming before this code is invoked?

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library - read this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code...

```js
function s() {
    alert("hello");
    var $email = document.getElementById("inp_subscribe").value;
    alert($email);
    $.get("subscribe.php",{inp_subscribe: $email },"");
    alert($email);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="inp_subscribe">Email:</label>
<input name="inp_subscribe" id="inp_subscribe" type="email"/>
<button onclick="s();">Submit</button>
```